# Styling HTML5 Elements and W3C

Tags: html, element, w3c

I am reading over HTML5 docs on W3C site now, and I just read this:

> Note: The section element is not a
>   generic container element. When an
>   element is needed for styling purposes
>   or as a convenience for scripting,
>   authors are encouraged to use the div
>   element instead. A general rule is
>   that the section element is
>   appropriate only if the element's
>   contents would be listed explicitly in
>   the document's outline.

So, I interpret that as "Do not style section elements. Use DIV instead." But I've seen a few websites that style all of the HTML5 elements, and guess what? I 'Viewed Source' of that W3C link below where it says not to style a section element, and they styled it themselves! WTF?
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element

Or should I interpret the above statement as:

"You can style section elements, so long as the contents of the section element would be listed explicitely in the document's outline."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML5 spec does *not* state that you shouldn't apply CSS styles to the `section` tag, but rather that you shouldn't include `section` tags *simply* for styling/scripting purposes, as that affects the semantic layout of your document.

From [the section about `section`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element):

> The `section` element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a **thematic grouping of content**, typically **with a heading**. [emphasis added]

Compare to [the section about `div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element):

> `div` elements can be useful for **stylistic purposes** or to **wrap multiple paragraphs within a section** that are all to be **annotated in a similar way**. [emphasis added]

Comment: It does say that, I copied and pasted right from the W3C site!

Comment: I quoted their exact wording in my question. *When an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead* - it says theyre encouraged **not** to style them, and to use the div instead.